# Hailstorm damaged garden-will carrots and beets recover?

Tags: vegetables

A bad hailstorm and 60 miles/per hour winds damaged my garden here in western Montana. My carrots and beets are all missing several leaves. Will they sprout new leaves and still produce roots? I planted them last week of May.
Also, my onions lost all the top leaves (looks like they were chopped in the middle). Will they still produce bulbs? They haven't started producing bulbs yet.

My corn is shredded, Not dead, I'm hoping it will recover. It was all the way down, but is halfway up now.